# Can you provide a real world example of using Ethereum network?

Tags: mist, ether, dapps, network

Is there any practical real world example which you can provide in order to understand the simple benefits for using Ethereum network by the ordinary user?

Especially in terms of purchasing something that can make user's life much easier, efficient and less time consuming than using a standard method by a non-technical user (like PayPal or Skrill, not to mention standard method of paying by card)?